# Improve Ubuntu's two-finger scroll

Tags: mouse, touchpad, multi-touch

I am using Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS. It is possible to enable two-finger scrolling from the settings. But the feature is not as good as in Windows. When I scroll with the two fingers vertically, Windows works fine, but Ubuntu won't scroll. Ubuntu works well only up to 70 degrees. But I like to keep my two fingers in 90 degrees because my touchpad is on the left side, and keeping my right-hand fingers horizontal is painful.

Is there any way to solve this? For now, I am using edge scroll, but would love to use two-finger scroll.